# Finding corresponding trunk channel

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

I use Asterisk 16.5 and sip trunk.

If known sip channel can i find corresponding trunk channel?

**Note:** I want do it with Asterisk AMI.

Answer (score 0):

By default channel name is SIP/TRUNK_NAME-uniquepart. So just parse channel and you will get trunk

There are no channels in trunk. Digital trunks have no lines.